# Disk has 1TB but I can only use 7.7GB

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, storage

I bought this computer one year ago and it came with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I used the computer as it came and I didn't have problems until now when I can't even download photos because the storage is full.

In settings it says I only have 7,7GB s available even though on the computer specs it is 1TB.

I ran `lsblk` in the terminal and it does show that I have 1TB of space but I can only use 7,7GB for some reason.

How can I fix this?

```
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   3,8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    0   7,5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: You should be able to use GParted to increase the size of /, your root partition. You do not want to upgrade from 14.04 as you would be taking Unity with you. Better to reinstall, You can backup your home directory and reuse that. You can et ESP to prolong 14.04 security here if needed: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Comment: Close voters - only questions *specific* to the version in question should be closed as being about an old unsupported release. There is nothing specific to 14.04 about this question imho.

Answer (score 21):

If 14.04 LTS supports this, try using GParted to see the partitions in the disk. There is a good chance that the partition you are seeing (7.7GB) is the only formatted partition, and you might see "Free Space 9xx GB" or something of that nature. You only need to extend the partition (if possible).

Comment: Thats what i did and it worked,thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @Olariu Bgd If this answer helped you, you should click the check mark, upper left, to accept it. It helps the reputation of the person that answered it and makes them feel good.

Comment: Besides @C.S.Cameron comment you will get 2 points for accepting the answer and the author will get 15 points. People here don't get paid money, they get paid points.